# remove html element and new line from the string?

Tags: javascript

i have this code that works removing html elements:

```js
console.log("<p>Done is beautiful.  <\/p>\n".replace(/<(?:.|\n)*?>/gm, ''))
```

but i have difficulty with regExp removing \n, this would return

> 'my text \n'

How do i remove that \n on text?

Comment: wait, editing the question, the response from api quote is weird

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use `alternation ( | )`  in your regex

```
/<(?:.|\n)*?>|\n/
     |         |________ Matches new line
     |__________________ Matches `<` followed by any character followed by `>`
```

```js
console.log('<p>my text</p>\n some value'.replace(/<(?:.|\n)*?>|\n/gm, ''))
```

Comment: I'm not really sure, but I think you can simplify the regexp to `/<(?:.)*?>|\n/gm`.

Comment: @Shidersz no because this will miss case like `<\p
>` with new line in it, just watch textarea tag [here](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G2O728X99KGS)